# How to replace Facebook Discussions App

Tags: facebook

Facebook will remove the Discussions app on oct 31st.

What alternative could I use as a FB app to provide discussion functionality similar to the current app? The wall just doesn't work out. There seems to be no boxed solutions but I want to make sure before I build myself.

It'll also need importing of current discussions to which the only option seems to be screenscraping. Anyone build something like this already?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of discussion/forum apps.
Currently only one can import your board. I think it's called forum.

I can provide an sql file with all your topics and posts also a facebook app to host yourself.
If you are intrested, contact me.